# Error installing Biopython on ubuntu MATE

Tags: biopython

I'm trying to install biopython for my studies but I'm with the following problem:

building 'Bio.cpairwise2' extension
i686-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -02 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c Bio/cpairwise2module.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/Bio/cpairwise2module.o
unable to execute 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc': No such file or directory
error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

What can I do now? I'm have little experience with Linux and I have never experienced an error like this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not have the C compiler installed. The easy option under Ubuntu would be to get the Ubuntu Biopython package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-biopython
```

If that would be too old, then you can at least get all the build requirements (like a C compiler) with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-biopython
```

and then try installing Biopython from source.

See also http://biopython.org/wiki/Download#Ubuntu_or_Debian

Comment: Thank you! It Worked perfectly!